# message queue - thread safe

Tags: multithreading, queue

I need to use a thread-safe message queue which is also variable size. I searched but found no available solution which answers these. There is std:queue but it seems not to be thread safe nor variable size. It should be used on Linux, which also have some queue mechanism, but suitable better for processes and I'm afraid will be less effecient for thread.

Thanks for any suggestion,
Ran

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ has a pretty good article about thread safety.

http://zeromq.org/blog:multithreading-magic

The safest answer is not the comman answer.  The 0MQ folks based the design on Erlang concurrency.  Excuse the use of a link, it's a fairly detailed article.

Shorter answer.  Check out ZeroMQ.